# ElasticSearch or Fsharp crashing with this error

Tags: c#, reactjs, typescript, f#

I'm trying to read data from a node with elastic search but I'm getting this error whenever I try to. Is anyone familiar with this problem? The times when it passes, the response result is empty and contains no data. Have been trying to many possible ways and none of them seem to work, and this method has always been working until now.

```
Elasticsearch.Net.Exceptions.MaxRetryException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Failed after retrying 2 times: 'POST dev-news/newsarticle/_search'. 
InnerException: JsonSerializationException, InnerMessage: Cannot create and populate list type Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[Montel.Databus.Messages.News.Entities.Journalist]. Path 'hits.hits[0]._source.journalists', line 7, position 19., InnerStackTrace:    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewList(JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolvePropertyAndCreatorValues(JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, IDictionary`2& extensionData)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, ObjectConstructor`1 creator, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Populate(JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerProxy.PopulateInternal(JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Nest.ConcreteTypeConverter`1.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\Resolvers\Converters\ConcreteTypeConverter.cs:line 90
   at Nest.DefaultHitConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\Resolvers\Converters\ConcreteTypeConverter.cs:line 42
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Nest.NestSerializer.DeserializeUsingSettings[T](Stream stream, JsonSerializerSettings settings) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ExposedInternals\NestSerializer.cs:line 105
   at Nest.NestSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream stream) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ExposedInternals\NestSerializer.cs:line 85
   at Nest.NestSerializer.DeserializeInternal[T](Stream stream, JsonConverter converter) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ExposedInternals\NestSerializer.cs:line 94
   at Nest.ElasticClient.FieldsSearchDeserializer[T,TResult](IElasticsearchResponse response, Stream stream, ISearchRequest d) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ElasticClient-Search.cs:line 124
   at Nest.ElasticClient.<>c__DisplayClass513_0`2.<CreateSearchDeserializer>b__0(IElasticsearchResponse r, Stream s) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ElasticClient-Search.cs:line 136
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.StreamToTypedResponse[T](ElasticsearchResponse`1 streamResponse, ITransportRequestState requestState, Byte[] readBytes) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestHandlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 248
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.ReturnTypedResponse[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState, ElasticsearchResponse`1 streamResponse, ElasticsearchServerError& error) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestHandlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 109
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.CoordinateRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState, Int32 maxRetries, Int32 retried, Boolean& aliveResponse) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestHandlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 134
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.DoRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestHandlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 155
InnerException: JsonSerializationException, InnerMessage: Cannot create and populate list type Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[Montel.Databus.Messages.News.Entities.Journalist]. Path 'hits.hits[0]._source.journalists', line 7, position 19., InnerStackTrace:    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewList(JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolvePropertyAndCreatorValues(JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, IDictionary`2& extensionData)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, ObjectConstructor`1 creator, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Populate(JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerProxy.PopulateInternal(JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Nest.ConcreteTypeConverter`1.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\Resolvers\Converters\ConcreteTypeConverter.cs:line 90
   at Nest.DefaultHitConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\Resolvers\Converters\ConcreteTypeConverter.cs:line 36
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Nest.NestSerializer.DeserializeUsingSettings[T](Stream stream, JsonSerializerSettings settings) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ExposedInternals\NestSerializer.cs:line 105
   at Nest.NestSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream stream) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ExposedInternals\NestSerializer.cs:line 85
   at Nest.NestSerializer.DeserializeInternal[T](Stream stream, JsonConverter converter) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ExposedInternals\NestSerializer.cs:line 94
   at Nest.ElasticClient.FieldsSearchDeserializer[T,TResult](IElasticsearchResponse response, Stream stream, ISearchRequest d) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ElasticClient-Search.cs:line 124
   at Nest.ElasticClient.<>c__DisplayClass513_0`2.<CreateSearchDeserializer>b__0(IElasticsearchResponse r, Stream s) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ElasticClient-Search.cs:line 136
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.StreamToTypedResponse[T](ElasticsearchResponse`1 streamResponse, ITransportRequestState requestState, Byte[] readBytes) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestHandlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 248
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.ReturnTypedResponse[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState, ElasticsearchResponse`1 streamResponse, ElasticsearchServerError& error) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestHandlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 109
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.CoordinateRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState, Int32 maxRetries, Int32 retried, Boolean& aliveResponse) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestHandlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 134
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.DoRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestHandlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 155
InnerException: JsonSerializationException, InnerMessage: Cannot create and populate list type Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[Montel.Databus.Messages.News.Entities.Journalist]. Path 'hits.hits[0]._source.journalists', line 7, position 19., InnerStackTrace:    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewList(JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolvePropertyAndCreatorValues(JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, IDictionary`2& extensionData)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, ObjectConstructor`1 creator, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Populate(JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerProxy.PopulateInternal(JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Nest.ConcreteTypeConverter`1.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\Resolvers\Converters\ConcreteTypeConverter.cs:line 90
   at Nest.DefaultHitConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\Resolvers\Converters\ConcreteTypeConverter.cs:line 36
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Nest.NestSerializer.DeserializeUsingSettings[T](Stream stream, JsonSerializerSettings settings) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ExposedInternals\NestSerializer.cs:line 105
   at Nest.NestSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream stream) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ExposedInternals\NestSerializer.cs:line 85
   at Nest.NestSerializer.DeserializeInternal[T](Stream stream, JsonConverter converter) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ExposedInternals\NestSerializer.cs:line 94
   at Nest.ElasticClient.FieldsSearchDeserializer[T,TResult](IElasticsearchResponse response, Stream stream, ISearchRequest d) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ElasticClient-Search.cs:line 124
   at Nest.ElasticClient.<>c__DisplayClass513_0`2.<CreateSearchDeserializer>b__0(IElasticsearchResponse r, Stream s) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ElasticClient-Search.cs:line 136
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.StreamToTypedResponse[T](ElasticsearchResponse`1 streamResponse, ITransportRequestState requestState, Byte[] readBytes) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestHandlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 248
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.ReturnTypedResponse[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState, ElasticsearchResponse`1 streamResponse, ElasticsearchServerError& error) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestHandlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 109
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.CoordinateRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState, Int32 maxRetries, Int32 retried, Boolean& aliveResponse) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestHandlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 134
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.DoRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\RequestHandlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 155
  Source=Elasticsearch.Net
  StackTrace:
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandlerBase.ThrowMaxRetryExceptionWhenNeeded[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState, Int32 maxRetries)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.RetryRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.DoRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.RetryRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.DoRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.RetryRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.DoRequest[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.RequestHandlers.RequestHandler.Request[T](TransportRequestState`1 requestState, Object data)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Connection.Transport.DoRequest[T](String method, String path, Object data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClient.DoRequest[T](String method, String path, Object data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClient.Search[T](String index, String type, Object body, Func`2 requestParameters)
   at Nest.RawDispatch.SearchDispatch[T](ElasticsearchPathInfo`1 pathInfo, Object body)
   at Nest.ElasticClient.Search[T,TResult](Func`2 searchSelector)
   at Nest.ElasticClient.Search[T](Func`2 searchSelector)
   at Insider2008.WebApi.NewsController.SearchNewsArchive(NewsSearchDto search) in C:\Projects\MontelOnline\Insider2008\WebApi\NewsController.cs:line 125
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Inner Exception 1:
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.

Inner Exception 2:
JsonSerializationException: Cannot create and populate list type Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[Montel.Databus.Messages.News.Entities.Journalist]. Path 'hits.hits[0]._source.journalists', line 7, position 19.
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your results from `hits.hits[0]._source.journalists`. I think they are incorrect JSON format

Comment: Hi, the journalists looks like this:   `"journalists":[],"bylines":[],"`

I will try to comment out the part which filters the journalists and see if it still applies.

Comment: @KhoaLe I meant your REAL results which were received from your API. Make sure that your `NewsController.cs` return NOT NULL value.

Comment: How can I do this? :)